# Podcast #14 in MP3 format

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast

[The Stack Exchange podcast, episode 14](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-14) (number 99 in the old numbering system) file has a size of 369 MB ([WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) format?). Can we get an MP3 version (expected size 95 MB)?

Comment: "We have a brand new podcasting setup (again!)" explains everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been replaced with an MP3 version